# How to increase Splash Screen time in ionic for IOS devices

Tags: ios, delay, splash-screen, ionic-framework

I need to increase time delay of splash screen in ios devices. I'm using IONIC.

Following is my config file:

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

It's working in Android device by simply adjusting SplashScreenDelay. I don't know why splash screen is hiding automatically after setting AutoHideSplashScreen is false.

Answer (score 9):

You can disable the automatic handling of splash screen and programmatically hide it when the app is ready.

Originally from [ionicframework forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/white-page-showing-after-splash-screen-before-app-load/2908/9) (with slight changes):

Install the cordova splashscreen plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Make sure you have the following in config.xml of your project:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

In app.js, add the following in the `run` method:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 100);
```

After adding, the code should look as follows:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    // Hide splash screen
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 100);

    // some other things
  });
})
```

Answer (score 6):

We can implement this by installing  cordova splashscreen plugin .For more refer link http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/splash-screen/

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen

app.run(function($cordovaSplashscreen) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $cordovaSplashscreen.hide()
  }, 5000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
platforms\android\cordova\default.xml
```

You can add default configuration that is needed for config.xml.

At run time config.xml will changed by ionic framework so needs to change in default.xml will refelect in config.xml too.